# How to create a edit view for multiple model objects with no primary key?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am doing some calculations on the server side and displaying a table in a view. I want to be able to edit each row of the table in a single view.

How can I bind the model to the view so that after editing in the view I get a list of the model objects in the POST controller action?

My model:

```
    public class Item
    {
        public float floatValue1;
        public string stringValue1;
        public float floatValue2;
        public double doubleValue1;
    }
```

From this model, I created a table view that lists the values in a HTML table.
**However, in the edit view I don't need to edit each field**. For example, only `floatValue1`, `stringValue1`, `floatValue2` need to be editable. The `doubleValue1` should remain its current value and uneditable by the user.

I've tried the suggestions I found online:

My controller sends a list of `Item` objects to the edit view as an `IList<Item>`
The edit view has a html form with a `for` loop, each iteration creates a table row with Html.EditorFor

```
public ActionResult PricingEdit(int? i)
{
     var result = calculations();  // returns IList<Item>
     return View(result.ToList());
}
```

My edit view:

```
@model IList<Item> 
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit sheet";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("EditItems", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table class="table table-sm">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    floatValue1
                </th>
                <th>
                    stringValue1
                </th>
                <th>
                    floatValue2
                </th>
            </tr>

            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            @for(int i= 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x[i].floatValue1)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x[i].stringValue1)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x[i].floatValue2)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x[i].doubleValue1, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
    </table>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg mt-1" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

My HTTP POST controller action:

```
        public ActionResult EditItems(IList<Item> table)
        {

            return View(new List<Item>());
        }
```

I get a `List<Item>` of values in my action, but each item in the list has 0 or null values for the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model should have getters and setters so the model binder can set the values. It should work when your model matches the following:

```
public float floatValue1 { get; set; }
public string stringValue1 { get; set; }
public float floatValue2 { get; set; }
public double doubleValue1 { get; set; }
```

In C# it's usual to start properties like these with an uppercase so i advice you to change that.

Comment: No, I don't mind if the entire list is posted back. My issue is that the list I'm getting back in my edit controller action has no values for the fields.

Comment: Apologies for my misunderstanding. you were right and your code is almost working. I have updated my answer.